# No seller_id in dimensions but can create a count distinct measure on it in kylin sample cube

Tags: kylin

CDH: 5.7  Kylin: 1.5.2_CDH_5.7

In kylin sample cube kylin_sales_cube, there is a measure named SELLER_CNT_HLL which is COUNT_DISTINCT and uses the column seller_ID
but when I edit it I can't select the seller_id because there is no column named seller_id in the dropdown list and the seller_id is not a dimension in the cube

I am little confused about this, I don't know whether this is a mistake but this is what I want, the cardinality of seller_id is huge at actual situation I don't want seller_id be a dimension but I want the COUNT DISTINCT of seller_id and filter by a single seller_id

Please help me out with the confusion，thanks

Answer (score 0):

From kylin's dev mailing list I got the answer

`The "seller_id" was missed in data model's "measure" columns; Please edit 
the data model and add it there, and then when edit the cube, you will be 
able to select it the measure.`

http://apache-kylin.74782.x6.nabble.com/No-seller-id-in-dimensions-but-can-create-a-count-distinct-measure-on-it-in-kylin-sample-cube-td4813.html